# How can I choose the best model in cross validation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, svm, cross-validation

I have two datasets and I want to train a SVM classification model (`fitcsvm`) by one of them and then predict labels for the other one. I use 10-fold cross-validation (`crossval`) to train my model so I have 10 different models. My question is which one of these models are the best for prediction and how can I find that?
here is my code:

```
Mdl = fitcsvm(trainingData,labels);
CVMdl = crossval(Mdl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have mixed up something here. The function [`fitcsvm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) trains a single model and the function [`crossval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.htm) validates this single model. It will then return an evaluation value.

In general, you cannot *train a model by cross-validation* (as it says, it is a validation technique). However, you can use cross-validation to train good models.

What you are looking for is a sort of [**hyperparameter optimization**](https://kr.mathworks.com/help/stats/hyperparameter-optimization-in-classification-learner-app.html). Those are methods that automatically train multiple models on a given data set to find the best tuning values for the SVM. Have a look at the docs [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html#bvdn8ei-1)

You can turn it on like this

```
Mdl = fitcsvm(trainingData,labels,'OptimizeHyperparameters','auto')
```

You may want to use cross-validation to train multiple models with the same tuning parameters but I guess, you'll have to write this yourself. Perhaps this already helps you.